# Script that adopts non-sudo user cannot find command that is available to that user

Tags: bash, scripts

On my server,I have a script that is run by a sudo user. It includes the following lines:

```
sudo -u nonsudoer -H bash -l << HERE
echo -n "Execute code as user "; whoami
cd bundle/programs/server
echo -n "Install package at "; pwd
npm install --production
HERE
```

These lines produce this output:

```
Execute code as user nonsudoer
Install package at /var/www/example/bundle/programs/server
bash: line 4: npm: command not found
```

However, when I run these lines manually...

```
$ sudo -u nonsudoer -H bash -l
manpath: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct
$ echo -n "Execute code as user "; whoami
Execute code as user nonsudoer
$ cd bundle/programs/server
$ echo -n "Install package at "; pwd
Install package at /var/www/example/bundle/programs/server
$ npm install --production
  <command successful; output clipped>
$ exit
```

... everything works as expected. What am I doing wrong in my script?

Comment: Where is the path to npm defined? if it's in nonsudouser's `~/.bashrc` file, then my guess would be that it's failing because `bash -l` invokes the shell non-interactively, so `~/.bashrc` is either not read or read only up to the point where it tests for interactivity and bails.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you explain why `bash -l` works differently in a script than it does from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke the `bash -l` shell and then interact with it on the command line, the new bash login shell is *interactive*, as you can confirm by examining the value of special parameter `$-`:

```
steeldriver@machine:~$ sudo -u testuser -H bash -l
testuser@machine:/home/steeldriver$ echo $-
himBHs
testuser@machine:/home/steeldriver$ exit
logout
```

When you invoke `bash -l` via a here-document, you get a *non-interactive* login shell:

```
steeldriver@machine:~$ sudo -u testuser -H bash -l << HERE
echo \$-
HERE
hBs
steeldriver@machine:~$
```

(note that I escaped `$-` in order to prevent it from being expanded by the interactive parent shell).

According to `man bash`, bash login shells are initialized with `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile` if present) while non-login shells are initialized with `~/.bashrc`. Ubuntu muddies the waters somewhat by conditionally sourcing `~/.bashrc` from `~/.profile`. However the rc file has an interactivity check built in:

```
$ sudo -u testuser -H head /home/testuser/.bashrc
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

So in the non-interactive case, `~/.bashrc` bails almost immediately, bypassing any `PATH` specifications that you may have added later in the file, while in the interactive case, the whole of your `~/.bashrc` is processed (in spite of being in a login shell), and your npm `PATH` is likely being added there.